# ¿Por qué el segue 'entrar' se hace dos veces?

Tags: firebase, ios, swift, xcode

Cuando presiono el botón 'ingresar', mi código hace el segue 'entrar' dos veces y la consola muestra 'Entró' y 'No estamos logueados'. Intenté escribiendo la llamada a la función `sesionActiva()` en el `ViewDidLoad()` pero no funcionó. Quiero que el segue lo realice una sola vez.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class IniciarSesion: UIViewController {

//OUTLETS.
@IBOutlet weak var correo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

//FUNCIONES.
//MARK: ViewDidLoad().
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    correo.text = ""
    password.text = ""
}

//MARK: ViewDidAppear().
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    correo.text = ""
    password.text = ""

    sesionActiva()
}

//Funciones cuando se toca el botón 'Iniciar Sesión'.
@IBAction func ingresar(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if correo.text != "" && password.text != "" {
        guard let email = correo.text else { return }
        guard let contraseña = password.text else { return }
        inicioSesion(correo: email, pass: contraseña)
    } else {
        let alerta = UIAlertController(title: "Atención", message: "Ingrese correo electrónico y contraseña", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let aceptar = UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alerta.addAction(aceptar)
        present(alerta, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

//Inicio sesion con mail y contraseña ingresada, autenticando en Firebase.
func inicioSesion(correo: String, pass: String){
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: correo, password: pass){ (user, error) in
        if user != nil {
            print("Entró")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "entrar", sender: self)
        } else {
            if let error = error?.localizedDescription {
                print("Error en Firebase", error)
            } else {
                print("Error en el código")
            }
        }
    }
}

//Comprueba si la sesion estaba iniciada.
func sesionActiva(){
    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print("No estamos logueados")
        } else {
            print("Si estamos logueados")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "entrar", sender: self)
        }
    }
 }

}
```

Estoy utilizando **Firebase** para hacer un sistema de login. Funciona correctamente, pero estoy teniendo ese problema nomás.

Answer (score 1):

lo que pasa es que tenes 2 listeners que ejecutan el segue.
Vamos paso por paso:

Primero en el `ViewDidLoad` llamas a `sesionActiva()` donde agregas un `StateDidChangeListener` que se quedara escuchando si cambia algo en la `Auth`.

Luego en el boton de login llamas `Auth.auth().signIn...` que ademas de logear queda a la espera de que se termine el login correctamente.

Finalmente cuando el login sea exitoso se ejecutara el listener del `signIn` y tambien el de `StateDidChange` porque efectivamente el status acaba de cambiar.

Hay muchas formas de solucionar este problema. Creo que en este caso lo mas facil y rapido seria quitar el `performSegue` del signIn ya que de todas formas se ejecutará por el `stateDidChange`.

Recordá que en firebase cada vez que agregas un listener este queda en escucha activa, no es como una simple llamada a una api a la que consultas, responde y se acabo.